# Identify this ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, electric-motor, remote-control

I have this ceiling fan in my house. The previous owner didn't leave any documentation about it. It came with a remote, but unfortunately the remote's screen does not turn on, even with a fresh battery.

The fan:[image: fan]

Here is the fan with the upper cover removed:
[image: under upper cover]

Here is a close-up underneath the upper cover. This is the writing I can find on here. The other side looks roughly the same, but without any writing on it.
[image: under upper cover - closeup]

Here is the fan with the lamp cover removed:
[image: under lamp cover]

Here is a close-up underneath the lamp cover:
[image: under lamp cover - closeup]

Here is the remote that came with it. Unfortunately, even with a fresh battery, the screen on the remote does not turn on.
[image: remote control front]
[image: remote control back - with battery]
[image: remote control back - without battery]

Thanks in advance for your help! If we can figure out what kind of fan this is, I will try buying a new remote and see if that gets the fan going again.

Comment: google the fcc number

Comment: @jsotola Done. Here's what I've learned so far. (1) [It's a 304 MHz remote.](https://fccid.io/FO8UC7091T) (2) There are lots of ceiling-fan-related products with the numbers UC70XX. I am looking for a compatible remote now.

Comment: home depot shows replacement remote controls ... would not hurt to try one

Comment: @jsotola Good point. I am having trouble finding a remote that claims to be compatible with UC7091T. There are many replacement remotes for UC7078T and UC7081T. So, I think I will order a kit that contains a remote and a new receiver. If the remote doesn't work with my receiver, I will also install the new receiver.

Comment: have you looked closely at the fan assembly? ... there may be a label ... the blades may have a part number on them ... look on top side of the blades  ... it is quite possible that the remote control does not belong with the fan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fan itself still works you should be able to get an aftermarket remote control package that includes a new remote and receiver/controller and you can just swap out both of them for the new ones. Fan brand shouldn't matter.

Comment: DC fans generally don't work with generic remotes

Comment: I ended up buying one of those remote control packages and installing the receiver (replacing the old receiver to which I do not have a working remote). It works great now with a new remote.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a “Big Ass Fan”, maybe a “Haiku” model or “Haiku L” model. They come in sizes from 8’ to 14’ with various types of controllers.

You can Google them and then email your pictures to them.

Comment: Is that a brand name? Really? Sheesh... :/ Also, it's hard to tell without a reference, but that doesn't look to be an 8' diameter fan. Again, hard to tell...

Comment: **I read stack exchange, I find it feeds my little brain, I'm a big ass fan**.  Today's Haiku is inspired  by Lee Sam.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Great marketing, isn’t it.  You’ll never forget the name of that fan company. I’ve used them several times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find that this is a Modern Fan Company product. We have several Modern Fan  fans and each has this exact remote.